# How to insert a count column into a sql query

Tags: sql

I need the second column of the table retrieved from a query to have a count of the number of rows, so row one would have a 1, row 2 would have a 2 and so on.  I am not very proficient with sql so I am sorry if this is a simple task.

A basic example of what I am doing would be is:

```
SELECT [Name], [I_NEED_ROW_COUNT_HERE],[Age],[Gender]
FROM [customer]
```

The row count must be the second column and will act as an ID for each row.  It must be the second row as the text file it is generating will be sent to the state and they require a specific format.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First, you don't have to have select order exactly the same as the output you'll provide. You can always manipulate this data after gathering it from db.

Second, I think nobody will help you, because the question might be not possible to understand.

Can you provide more information? What exactly you need, and how the db schema looks like?

Comment: Have you looked at the usage of COUNT operator? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: @sznowicki, I suspect the data is going to be directly exported from the query tool.

Comment: I modified my answer to explain row number now that I understand you didn't mean count().

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With your edit, I see that you want a row **ID** (normally called [row number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) rather than "count") which is best gathered from a unique ID in the database (person_id or some other unique field). If that isn't possible, you can make one for this report with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID DESC) AS ID,` in your select statement.

```
select Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name DESC) AS ID,
Age, Gender
from customer
```

This function adds a field to the output called ID (see my tips at the bottom to describe aliases). Since this isn't in the database, it needs a method to determine how it will increment. After the over keyword it orders by Name in descending order.

---

**Information on Counting** follows (won't be unique by row):

If each customer has multiple entries but the selected fields are the same for that user and you are counting that user's records (summed in one result record for the user) then you would write:

```
select Name, count(*), Age, Gender
from customer
group by name, age, gender
```

This will count ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)) all the user's records as grouped by the name, age and gender (if they match, it's a single record).

However, if you are counting all records so that your whole report has the grand total on every line, then you want:

```
select Name, (select count(*) from customer) as "count", Age, Gender
from customer
```

**TIP:** If you're using something like SSMS to write a query, dragging in columns will put brackets around the columns. This is only necessary if you have spaces in column names, but a DBA will tend to avoid that like the plague. Also, if you need a column header to be something specific, you can use the as keyword like in my first example.

> [W3Schools has a good tutorial on count()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)
>
> The `COUNT(column_name)` function returns
>   the number of values (NULL values will not be counted) of the
>   specified column:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

> The `COUNT(*)` function returns the number of records in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

> The `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)` function returns the number of
>   distinct values of the specified column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

> `COUNT(DISTINCT)` works with ORACLE and Microsoft SQL Server, but
>   not with Microsoft Access.

Comment: Your inner query won't quite work. And yet if it did work then it would return a 1.

Comment: Thanks. My keyboard must have jumped. I fixed it in both places.

Answer (score 3):

It's odd to repeat the same number in every row but it sounds like this is what you're asking for. And note that this might not work in your flavor of SQL. MS Access?

```
SELECT [Name], (select count(*) from [customer]), [Age], [Gender]
FROM [customer]
```

Comment: I worded it poorly, I need each row to display which number row that is.  So row 1 would have 1 in that column, 2 would have 2 and so on.  Like an id generator.  It is in visual studio c# but i am retrieving data from an sql database in sql server management studio

Comment: You might have been thinking of the word "counter" rather than just "count'. I think that might have cleared up some of the confusion although it's still good to note that SQL is set-based and so we frequently try not to think in terms of row numbers and such.